# Importing Swift classes from a react-native-library into an example app written in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

### Background

I am building a react-native-library created from @react-native-community/bob with Swift for iOS and Kotlin for Android. The template provides an example app to test the module/library created. The example app is built in Objective-C. I am trying to import a Swift class to open a URL and therefore implemented the following function in swift:

```
@objc func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool { }
```

which is part of a class as such:

```
@objc(SwiftClassName) open class SwiftClassName: NSObject { 
    @objc func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool { }
}
```

### Problem

This function must be implemented within the Objective-C AppDelegate.m file within my example app in-order for the URL to be opened and the instance returned to Swift, as such:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)URL options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options {
    return [[SwiftClassName sharedInstance] app:app openURL:URL options:options];
}
```

### Issue

Everything is linked correctly and I can see the module/library within my example app but I cannot call the class which implements the function (i.e. SwiftClassName)

### What I've Tried

**NOTE: The ProjectName and ProjectModuleName are the same for my project**

Within my AppDelegate.h file import the following:

```
@class SwiftClassName
```

Within my AppDelegate.m file import the following:

```
#import <ProjectName/ProjectModuleName-Swift.h>
```

The above `#import` statement is where the errors start.

- Whether I try `#import <ProjectName/ProjectModuleName-Swift.h>` or `#import "ProjectModuleName-Swift.h"` I get a `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue` and of course `File Not Found`
- If I remove the `#import` statement, since I declare `@class SwiftClassName` in AppDelegate.h I get the errors:

  - `Receiver type 'SwiftClassName' for instance message is a forward declaration`
  - `Receiver 'SwiftClassName' for class message is a forward declaration`

Within the Swift Xcode Project I have the following checked for both the PROJECT and TARGET:

- Derives Modules → YES
- Always Embed Swift Standard Library → YES
- Install Objective-C Compatibility Headers → YES

### Question

How can I get the Objective-C example app to access my Swift class so that I can implement the necessary callback function within my app?

### My Guess

It seems as though the library project does not create the `TargetName-Swift.h` file and as such I can not implement the function. But that's just my guess. I can't see it anywhere within the folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/
    DerivedData/
        CurrentXcodeProject-ducoaakebhutnrdndbmrrakyafki/
            Build/
                Intermediates.noindex/
                    CurrentXcodeProject.build/
                        Debug-iphonesimulator/
                            CurrentXcodeProject.build/
```

I have read that under `Debug-iphonesimulator/CurrentXcodeProject.build/` I should be seeing a `DerivedData` folder containing the mentioning `TargetName-Swift.h` file but there is no such thing.

#### Info

OS: macOS 
React-Native Version: 0.62.2

Please let me know if you require any additional information to find a solution to this issue as I have literally come to a dead end.

Comment: I've just at the same point, and have the same thoughts - seems like in react-native app just not generated ProjectName-Swift.h file. Have you success to found the solution?